# Bivariate random variables normality check

Tags: multivariate-analysis, normality-assumption, bivariate

If there is a high correlation between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ (dependent), does that mean that they are normally distributed? Confusion i have is that both variables can be exponential in that case they can have a higher dependency. So if i want to check the normality do i have to check the normality of each variable separately and the perform next operations? One more thing if both variables are independent , does that mean that they are not normally distributed?

Comment: The nature of these questions suggests you might benefit from reviewing the definitions of "normal distribution" and "independent."  Since the concepts have nothing to do with one another, the answers to your questions ought to be clear.

Comment: Consider some X from some arbitrary distribution F. Let Y=X.  What's cor(X,Y)?